# How to stub out jquery in my asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am using Rails 3.2 and the jquery-ui-rails plugin to add the datepicker to my JS manifest file.

This is my manifest file:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require_tree .
```

I am getting my jQuery library separately from Google's CDN.

However, by adding jquery.ui to the manifest file, it automatically includes its jQuery dependency - so now I end up with two jQueries on my final HTML document.

I don't want this additional jQuery file - I only want the one from Google's CDN. Using sprockets, I can use the stub directive to selectively 'exclude' the jQuery file.

So this what I did - and it doesn't work - ie jQuery is still added to my final JS file ...

```
//= stub jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require_tree .
```

I have tried several combinations:

```
//= stub jquery.js

//= stub "jquery"

//= stub "jquery.js"

//= stub "/jquery.js"
```

etc ...

But none of these work. I haven't been able to find an example anywhere of how this is supposed to work. Incidentally, I have also tried

```
//= stub jquery_ujs
```

Which didn't stub out the jquery_ujs library either ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason why it doesn't work is that Rails 3.2.x only uses sprockets v2.1. Stubs, however, are only available in sprockets >= 2.2. You could try manually updating sprockets (forking actionpack).

Answer (score 0):

You could always just take the [jquery_ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L291) file, throw it into `vendor/javascripts`, remove the`jquery-rails` line from your Gemfile, and then include that vendored js in your manifest.